# web-addin fails to load after opening addin in more than 25 email windows at a time

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

If user opens Outlook Web Add-in in more than 25 mails at a time, it stops loading.

Then it is displaying error message :

> **ADDIN-ERROR :**
>
> This add-in could not be started. Close this dialog to ignore the problem or click "Restart" to try again.

It is not responding even if I click the "Restart" button.

This issue is only happening on Outlook 2016 for Windows.

Also this does not seem specific to my add-in. I have installed some other popular add-ins and have reproduced the same error.

Check the screenshot : 
[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "more than 25 mails at a time"? Are you saying if the user opens up 25 distinct email windows and loads the add-in in each, it starts failing after 25 instances? Or are you saying if a user loads an add-in 25 consecutive times it will fail starting with the 26th?

Comment: I mean user opens more than 25 to 30 emails at a time in distinct windows and enable plugin all windows.

Comment: Is this by chance machine dependent? If I had to guess, it may be just running out of resources. That is a lot of windows with a lot of embedded browsers going.

Comment: our observation : In JS plugin, when a new outlook window is created, a new IE process is created to render our plugin pane. If multiple windows are opened, for the same IE process the memory grows (it is like a new tab of IE browser). So once the window count reaches around 25 windows, OS can not allocate more memory to that IE process. Hence the JS plugin is showing the error, but the outlook is not disturbed only the js plugin pane will not be loaded since the pane is running in an independent IE process which wont effect the OUTLOOK process.

Comment: If this is inherent limitation in windows platform, can you mention in documentaion as limitation or do not load plugin in such cases.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.  We apologize for any frustration or inconvenience we have caused with this issue.  Please be patient as we work to fix this issue as quickly as we can. 

Thanks again for your feedback,
Outlook Engineering Team

Comment: After investigating, this error will be hit when Internet Explorer cannot allocate anymore memory. This seems to be variable depending on the machine/capability. We are looking into improving the error messaging here, and also seeing what fixes are available, but there is no timeframe on delivery for either of those. In the meantime, this issue can be mitigated by reducing the memory footprint of an add-in as much as possible. As it is not the # of instances of an add-in that has booted, but how much memory it takes up. (you can view the size of the IE Process in the process explorer)